# A Little Riddle

Tags: riddle

Here's a little riddle!

> Many languages spoken in my prefix
>   Many stars found in my suffix
>   Many clauses written in my whole

What am I?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You are:

> An [End User License Agreement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-user_license_agreement) (**EULA**)

*Many languages spoken in my prefix*

> **EU** - the European Union, which has 24 official languages.

*Many stars found in my suffix*

> **LA** - Los Angeles, home to Hollywood (solved by @greysaff)

*Many clauses written in my whole*

> My word, there really are - to the point that most people don't bother reading the whole thing before ticking the 'I Accept' box!

Answer (score 5):

Is the word..

> novella ?

Many languages spoken in my prefix

> no: means "no" in English, Spanish, and Italian

Many stars found in my suffix

> la: many Hollywood stars reside in Los Angeles

Many clauses written in my whole

> novella: as with most works of literature is composed of multiple clauses

Comment: You get the suffix part right

Answer (score 3):

I think it is:

> unlikely

Many languages spoken in my prefix:

> un -> United Nations

Many stars found in my suffix:

> ly -> light-year

Many clauses written in my whole:

> unlikely, common adj./adv. used in clauses (a bit not sure...)

**Enhanced Answer:**
Based on the comment under GreySaff's answer, might be:

> formula

Many languages spoken in my prefix:

> for -> preposition in many languages

Many stars found in my suffix:

> la -> L.A. Hollywood

Many clauses written in my whole:

> formula -> logic true/false clause like A->B, A v B

Comment: Unfortunately that's not it. You can wait til I drop a hint :)

Comment: @Luke May I ask that the prefix and suffix are correct or not in my answer? :P
(I just knew that the whole part is bit far-fetched...)

Comment: Not yet. Let's wait for some time.

Answer (score 1):

Many languages spoken in my prefix

> **for**, especially on many programming languages *for* iterations.

Many stars found in my suffix (answered on @greysaff)

> **la**, the Los Angeles, the place for Hollywood stars.

Many clauses written in my whole

> **formula**, to be precise in [logic formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clause_(logic)), e.g. 3-SAT.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer could be

> Cola

Many languages spoken in my prefix

> **CoL** refers to the [City of London](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_of_London)

Many stars found in my suffix (solved by greysaff)

> **LA**

Many clauses written in my whole

> **COLA**, stands for [Cost-of-Living Adjustment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cost_of_living)

Comment: I didn't think of this before, but what a great guess! Your answer is structurally the closest to the approved answer :)