# Variable Prefixes and Suffixes

Tags: riddle, word

> My short prefix will take you in.
> My long prefix is set against.
>
> My short suffix will take you in.
> My long suffix is in the country.
>
> Many clauses are written in my whole.

What am I?

Comment: Inspired by [this recent riddle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/87925/5373) although the answer is different.

Comment: What do you mean the answer is different? That one is still unanswered!

Comment: @CinCout Well, I know the answer to this one, and I'm fairly sure it doesn't fit as an answer to the previous one :-)

Comment: Haha okay. That makes sense.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My short prefix will take you in.

> con - a fraud.

My long prefix is set against.

> contra - opposed to.

My short suffix will take you in.

> act - a performance.

My long suffix is in the country.

> tract - piece of land.

Many clauses are written in my whole. What am I?

> **contract**  - this includes many clauses.

Comment: Nice one! You're too good at these word puzzles :-) (And good edit: the word *without* the "or" on the end was what I was looking for.)

Comment: @Rand - the word with 'or' at the end was maybe the reason I got it!